# 画像をアップロードする際、画面が切れているのかアップロードできない

Tags: バグ, 再現性なし

画像をアップロードする際、画面が切れているのかアップロードできない
自分だけなのか、画像を載せると cancel and add another image の文字しか出てこない
もしくは、画像選択がいけないのか
私がいけないのでしょうか？
教えてくださいm(--)m

Comment: OSとブラウザを教えてくれますか？

Comment: それは正常動作ではないでしょうか。私の環境でも変更用のインターフェイスとしては「cancel and add another image」の文字しか出ませんが、この文字をクリックすると画像が変更（選び直し）出来ます。（それとも、「画像の追加」ボタンが出なくて、アップロードが出来ないという事でしょうか。）

Comment: OSはOSX Yosemite バージョン10.10.3です。
ブラウザはSafari。
「画像の追加」するボタンが見当たりませんでした。

Comment: スクリーンショットがあるとわかりやすいのですが・・・それも難しいでしょうか。確かに、ウィンドウの高さがとても低い（400pxぐらい）場合は、ポップアップ右下の「画像の追加」ボタンが隠れることになります。（隠れる寸前の例： http://i.stack.imgur.com/fKLKg.png ）

Comment: タイトルや本文に「（画像）変更」と書かれていましたが、どうやら「upload」のことを指しているようなので「アップロード」としました。

Comment: 私のPCでは上の白い部分しか写りませんでした
が、設定を変えたら改善できました！
協力ありがとうございました！